# regex syntax stop search

Tags: c#, regex

How do I make Regex stop the search after "Target This"?

```
HeaderText="Target This" AnotherAttribute="Getting Picked Up"
```

This is what i've tried

```
var match = Regex.Match(string1, @"(?<=HeaderText=\").*(?=\")");
```

Comment: Why are you trying to parse XML with regex in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantifier `*` is **eager**, which means it will consume as many characters as it can while still getting a match. You want the **lazy** quantifier, `*?`.

As an aside, rather than using look-around expressions as you have done here, you may find it in general easier to use capturing groups:

```
var match = Regex.Match(string1, "HeaderText=\"(.*?)\"");
                                               ^   ^ these make a capturing group
```

Now the *`match`* matches the whole thing, but `match.Groups[1]` is just the value in the quotes.

Comment: +1. Good idea with the group capturing. `match.Groups[0]` is the whole match, therfore the first explicit group is group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Plain regex pattern

```
(?<=HeaderText=").*?(?=")
```

or as string

```
string pattern = "(?<=HeaderText=\").*?(?=\")";
```

or using a verbatim string

```
string pattern = @"(?<=HeaderText="").*?(?="")";
```

The trick is the question mark after `.*`. It means "as few as possible", making it stop after the first end-quotes it encounters.

Note that verbatim strings (introduced with `@`) do not recognize the backslash `\` as escape character. Escape the double quotes by doubling them.

Note for others interested in regex: The search pattern used finds a postion between a prefix and a suffix:

```
(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var match = Regex.Match(string1, "HeaderText=\"([^\"]+)");
var val = match.Groups[1].Value; //Target This
```

**UPDATE**
if there possibilities have double quotes in target,change the regex to:

```
HeaderText=\"(.+?)\"\\s+\\w
```

Note: it's not right way to do this, if it's a XML, check out [System.XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) otherwise,[HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) / [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack).